# select tag issue

Tags: css

I have used following css for `select` tag:

```
select {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #A96800;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Verdana","Lucida Fax","Lucida Grande","Lucida Sans   Unicode",Arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 10pt;
  height: 21px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 3px;
  width: 260px;
}
```

This css affects the text also.

Comment: what do you want to ask?

Comment: Its not clear what do you want to say. Put more detailed explanation of your problem.

Comment: This is not even a question. But, if I imagine what your question is, and by 'text' you mean regular text (not the text in your select, which is logically styled by this CSS rule) then you haven't closed the select properly.

Comment: I have applied the select tag. But it affects the <option> tag text color.

Comment: Please refer the location: http://jsfiddle.net/UJMkN/

Comment: See the answer. remove color: #fff; from your css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are unable to see the options because in your css, you are setting text's color to white.

```
color: #fff;
```

Just remove the above line so that your css looks like:

```
select {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #A96800;
  font-family: "Verdana","Lucida Fax","Lucida Grande","Lucida Sans   Unicode",Arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 10pt;
  height: 21px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 3px;
  width: 260px;
}
```

Now you can view your options as well.

Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UJMkN/1/

Hope this helps.